# Alias domain to noip without noip plus

Tags: networking, dns

My buddy's ISP does not offer any sort of plan with a static IP. He has recently purchased a domain from Google.  He has No-IP setup, but can't afford no-IP plus. CNAME and DNAME records make it impossible to forward the domain root, so is there a different way to alias his domain to noip that supports the root record? Or perhaps there's a better way to go about doing this?

What is the best course of action to get his domain pointing to his home network?

Comment: "What is the best course of action to get his domain pointing to his home network?" - Spend the $0.01 per day to accomplish what they want with the service they have chosen.

Comment: Since you have your own domain, one free option would be to make [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) your DNS provider and [set up `ddclient` to update the domain through Cloudflare's API](http://web.archive.org/web/20170526225334/https://www.techandme.se/setup-multiple-accounts-with-ddclient-and-cloudflare/).